# AngularFire2 query collection for documents that have a value within an array efficiently

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following model in an Angular 6 cli/TS/AngularFire thing I'm trying to build. I'm new to all of those things.

```
export class Book {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public title: string,
    public genres: any[]

  ) {}
}
```

And I want to be able to find all books that matcha genre stored in Firebase's Cloud Firestore using AngularFire2.

A standard query looks like this ([documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md)):

```
afs.collection('books', ref => ref.where('size', '==', 'large'))
```

Ideally, I want to make a call to Firebase that doesn't get all documents in the collection so it's more efficient (tell me if that's wrong thinking). For example, something like this.

```
afs.collection('books', ref => ref.where(book.genres.containsAny(array of user defined genres)));
```

I have a limited understanding of NoSQL data modeling, but would happily change the model if there's something more effective that will stay fast with 1000 or 30,000 or even 100,000 documents.

Right now I am doing this.

```
 filterArray = ["Genetic Engineering", "Science Fiction"];
 filteredBooks: Book[] = [];
 ngOnInit() {

    this.db.collection<Book>('books')
     .valueChanges().subscribe(books => {
       for (var i=0; i < books.length; i++) {
         if (books[i].genres.some(v => this.filterArray.includes(v))) {
           this.filteredBooks.push(books[i]);
         }
       }
    });
 }
```

This works to filter the documents, but is there a more efficient way both in terms of speed and scalability (get only the matching documents instead of all)?

Answer (score 0):

You're right to limit the documents first. You don't want to pull 30K documents, THEN filter them.  And you are on the right path, but your formatting wasn't quite right.  You want to do something like this:

```
afs.collection<book>('books', ref => ref.where('genres', 'array-contains', genre)
```

I believe that as of right now, you cannot pass in an array like:

```
afs.collection<book>('books', ref => ref.where('genres', 'array-contains', genres) // note that genres is plural implying a list of genres
```

However, it still may be better to do a for-loop through the genres and pull the books list, once for each genre, and concatenate the lists afterward.

Now, you mentioned that you would also like a suggestion to store the data differently. I would recommend that you do NOT use an array for genres. Instead make it a map (basically, an object), like this:

```
author: string;
title: string;
...
genres: map
```

Then you can do this:

```
author: 'Herman Melville'
title: 'Moby Dick'
...
genres: {
    'classics': true
    'nautical': true
}
```

And then you can filter the collection like this:

```
afs.collection<book>('books', ref => ref.where('genres.classics', '==', true).where('genres.nautical', '==' true)
```

I hope this helps